# Model changes not updating the view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a button listening for a click event , the idea is to toggle the state when the button is clicked.

The view :

```
<button  ng-click="nextBtnClicked()" ng-disabled="{{state == 1}}" class="btn">Call</button>
```

The controller :

```
app.controller('workStation',['$scope',function($scope)
{
    $scope.state = 0;
    $scope.nextBtnClicked = function()
    {
       $scope.state = 1;
    };
}]
```

The problem is that I don't see the changes when the button is clicked.I've also tried to execute $apply() but I got the error "Error:[$rootScope:inprog]"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use interpolation.

Use:

```
ng-disabled="state == 1"
```

Otherwise:

```
ng-disabled="{{state == 1}}"
```

Will be evaulated into:

```
ng-disabled="false"
```

Which means the `ngDisabled` directive will be watching a variable named `false` on the associated scope.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ng-click="state= !state"
```

This will toggle the state each time you click the button.

and

```
ng-disabled="state==1"
```

to disable the button when state is 1.